# Why holder space is more appropriate than $C^2(\Omega)$ for elliptic equation

Tags: elliptic-equations, partial-differential-equations

The Holder space has been extensively used in elliptic equation. I am just wondering why it is a more 
proper choice than $C^2(\Omega)$ in elliptic theory

Comment: Because one can prove sharp *a priori* estimates unavailable for $C^k$.

Comment: I would say, a bit for the same reason that $1/|x|$ is not in $L^1$ but quite close to be in $L^1$.